# how to call class method in apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

my class is

```
    public class Usage {
        public static void updateAccount(Usage__c[] usageLogs) {
            for (Usage__c u :usageLogs) {
                Account myAccount = [SELECT Id, ASEO_Last_Access__c FROM Account WHERE ASEO_Company_Id__c = :u.Company_Id__c];
                myAccount.ASEO_Last_Access__c = datetime.now();
                update myAccount;
                u.Account__c = myAccount.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

and trigger

```
trigger triger on Compnay__c(before insert){
  Company__c [] compny= tigger.new 
  updateAccount(compny)  
}
```

getting error

Comment: Your trigger code doesn't look like it could even compile besides that call to updateAccount. Updated there is only a single syntax issue left.

Comment: Riaz, it's helpfull if you post as much details as you can. At the very least the error you are receiving and why you do not understand it. This helps us help you, allowing for better answers.

Answer (score 4):

Theres a **lot** wrong with that code:

- The trigger should be firing on `Company__c` not `Compnay__c`
- All lines of code need to be closed with a `;` symbol. eg `Company__c [] compny= trigger.new;`
- Its `trigger.new` not `tigger.new`
- You are not calling the `updateAccount` method correctly. It should be `Usage.updateAccount(compny);`
- `Usage.updateAccount` is expecting a List of `Usage__c` objects not a List of `Company__c` objects.
- Your trigger is firing `before insert` (ie before an Id is assigned to the Company record) but your method is doing a query by Company Ids which will not find the newly inserted objects
- You're doing a SOQL call in a `for loop` which should be avoided as you will hit governor limits very quickly
- `updateAccount` is changing a field on `Usage__c` (`u.Account__c = myAccount.Id;`) but you don't do an update on the object so the change never gets persisted

Your trigger is probably supposed to look something like:

```
trigger meaningfulName on Company__c(after insert){
   List<Usage__c> usages = new List<Usage__c>();
   for (Company__c c : Tigger.new) {
       usages.add(new Usage(c)); // Assuming that there is a constructor for Usage 
   }
   if (usages.size() > 0) {
       Usage.updateAccount(usages);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`updateAccount` is a static method, so you have to prepend it's name with class name when calling (like in Java):

```
trigger triger on Company__c(before insert){
  Company__c [] compny= trigger.new;
  Usage.updateAccount(compny);
}
```